# Render nested JSON data in Reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

I would like to render the "Description" potion of my JSON file into a Reactjs list.

Here's my App.js

```
import  log from './logs/log'


function App() {
    const data = log["TProgramLogSerialize"].["ProgramLog"].["TProgramLogItem"].map((song, key) => (
        <li key={key}>{song.Description}</li>
    ))

    return (
        <ul>
          {data}
        </ul>
      );
}

export default App
```

The JSON file is:

```
{
  "TProgramLogSerialize": {
    "FileName": "KKGB-FM-DA-6-12-2021-OPX2",
    "AirDate": "06/12/2021",
    "ProgramLog": {
      "TProgramLogItem": [
        {
          "Category": "MACRO",
          "From": "CLOCKS",
          "Description": "LOADSCHED REMOTE VT",
        },
        {
          "Category": "MACRO",
          "From": "CLOCKS",
          "Description": "SCHED ON",
        },
        {
          "Category": {},
          "From": "MUSIC",
          "Description": "NEW POSITIONERS",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result shows:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean to access the properties without periods: `log["TProgramLogSerialize"]["ProgramLog"]["TProgramLogItem"]`. Or you can do `log.TProgramLogSerialize.ProgramLog.TProgramLogItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain what the issue is (I just plugged it into a codesandbox and it worked).  However, as Nick said, the periods with the square brackets aren't necessary.  You can access nested date like so:
`const data = log.TProgramLogSerialize.ProgramLog.TProgramLogItem.map`
or
`const data = log["TProgramLogSerialize"]["ProgramLog"]["TProgramLogItem"].map`
Meaning that you can do this:

```
//App.js
import log from "./logs";

function App() {
  const data = log.TProgramLogSerialize.ProgramLog.TProgramLogItem.map(
    (song, key) => <li key={key}>{song.Description}</li>
  );

  return <ul>{data}</ul>;
}

export default App;
```

```
//log.js
const log = {
  "TProgramLogSerialize": {
    "FileName": "KKGB-FM-DA-6-12-2021-OPX2",
    "AirDate": "06/12/2021",
    "ProgramLog": {
      "TProgramLogItem": [
        {
          "Category": "MACRO",
          "From": "CLOCKS",
          "Description": "LOADSCHED REMOTE VT",
        },
        {
          "Category": "MACRO",
          "From": "CLOCKS",
          "Description": "SCHED ON",
        },
        {
          "Category": {},
          "From": "MUSIC",
          "Description": "NEW POSITIONERS",
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

export default log
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-waterfall-xs15i?file=/src/App.js